# rar extraction failing

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, extract, rar

When I try to extract a file using rar it is outputting failed on random files.

My command:

`unrar x arma.rar`

What is causing this problem?

OS is Ubuntu 12.04

Edit - it is also happening on different rar files as well as a rar file that I created myself.

Comment: Is this for every .rar file you try, or only for the one you specified? Try to make a .rar file with >3 files yourself, and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake, it's not happening consistently with every third file. Files are failing with other rar files as well, not just this one, including one I rar'd myself.

Comment: If you're sure the archives aren't corrupted I recommend you start by testing your HDD and RAM.